# /etc/login.defs settings not taken into account: password aging

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, login, pam, debugging

*The following is done on a Ubuntu 20.04 system.*

This is the scenario where I am facing an issue:

- I edit the password aging settings in the `login.defs` file
- Then I change the password of the user with `passwd user` command
- I check what settings were applied to the password of the user with the `chage -l user` command

**The issue:**

The values returned seem not to be taking into account the changes made to the /etc/login.defs file.

Is there any reason for this?

How could I debug the issue? (e.g.: how to see what other settings may be tampering the values from the `/etc/login.defs`?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The man page is pretty clear about this:

```
        PASS_MAX_DAYS, PASS_MIN_DAYS and PASS_WARN_AGE are only used at the
        time of account creation. Any changes to these settings won't affect
        existing accounts.
```

Comment: Indeed, my lack of knowledge betrayed me yet again! Thank you @michael-hampton for your answer, and for helping me out on this!